# How to add a swing component to a Java 3D Applet?

Tags: java, swing, java-3d

I have made a Java 3D applet which basically displays a  3D graph with nodes(the nodes are spherical). Now, I want a side panel which contains a list of these nodes,so when I click on a node, the corresponding entry in the side panel should get highlighted/checked(if its a check box) Can anyone please help me as to how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Try limiting the size of the Canvus for your graph and place it in your JFrame. Then put your JPanel into your JFram. Should work thought i have problems with JPanels being in there correct spot.